# X.PagedList.Mvc Installation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

When I install `X.PagedList.Mvc` package to my application there is a dialog box, as seen in the picture below:

[image]

To install this package, there are so many library that should be installed. I don't get the same thing when install `PagedList.Mvc`.

Why is this different from the `PagedList`?

I'm just thinking, the list of libraries below are not related to `X.PagedList`, so that I click cancel and it won't install the package.

Note (if needed): 
I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5, Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: It is possibly because of the depedency on .NET Standard 1.6.1 that it downloads all these packages.

Comment: @NickPolideropoulos How to exclude those libraries as I'm still using .NET Framework?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can without breaking the dependencies on X.PagedList